# How to split a big folder into multiple standalone archives using RAR or 7-Zip console?

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, archiving, rar

Example: I want to add a 100 GB folder to archives of 10 GB each using **RAR** or **7-Zip** console on Windows. But each archive must be independent/standalone and able to extract without the other archives. I can split into multiple archives using the commands below.

**WinRar:**

```
rar.exe a -v10g -m0 output.rar inputdir
```

**7-Zip:**

```
7za.exe a -v10g -m0=Copy output.7z inputdir
```

But when I do this each archive needs one another. They cannot be uncompressed as individual archives.

There is a *PowerShell* approach which is very slow and high on resources. Also much more complex to change options/parameters/arguments. I really don't like it.

Some sources:

- [Split to volumes using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553787/split-to-volumes-using-batch)
- [ZIP a folder of files into multiple "stand-alone" ZIP files of maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75423366/zip-a-folder-of-files-into-multiple-stand-alone-zip-files-of-maximum-size)

How to get this done using **RAR** or **7-Zip** console?

Comment: Do you care how the files are grouped in the archives? Are they all consistent file sizes and types?